# Is there any way to gain access to Evasion without taking multiple levels of a class?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

So, I have a character with a *really, really, really* bonkers Reflex save. It wasn't really the design plan, but a combination of class features, ancillary benefits from traits, and stats meant that I ended up with one.

Given that, Evasion would be a really great feature to have - better still, the Twist Away feat, which requires Evasion, would be *incredible* for this particular character, and thematically fitting.

Problem is, dipping 2 levels of Rogue (or another class) is a larger setback than I'd like.

So, is there any way to get Evasion through a feat or other means? I'm particularly interested in **permanent** methods, in order to qualify for other feats. One level dips are worth mentioning, but not ideal, and if it helps any, the character is Mythic, on the Trickster path, and can expect to get to Tier 10 'someday' (but not anytime soon).

I'm interested in solutions that might apply for any race/class/level combination, as it seems a handy thing to pick up in a variety of circumstances - especially since Twist Away exists. That said, my particular circumstance is a Half Elf, Swash 1/Investigator 7 (the ACG versions).

Answer (score 11):

No permanent, non-dipping solution comes to mind, but otherwise the Core Rulebook item [Ring of Evasion](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magicItems/rings.html#ring-of-evasion) (25,000 gp) fits the bill.

Edit: Just so it's clear, this ring does not bestow upon the wearer the Evasion class feature, but *as if*:

> This ring continually grants the wearer the ability to avoid damage as
>   if she had evasion. Whenever she makes a Reflex saving throw to
>   determine whether she takes half damage, a successful save results in
>   no damage.

It comes down to the same thing, except it does not act as a prerequisite for other feats or class features.

Answer (score 7):

There is a [Ring of Evasion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/rings/ring-of-evasion), which grants the same abilities as the Evasion class feature.

But this won't let you qualify for other feats *(unless you have a lenient DM)*.

There are various classes that gain Evasion, but the quickest comes with 2 levels of Rogue, Monk, Shadowdancer, Demolisher, Pugilist or Time Thief. (Refer to the [d20PFSRD](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/) for details on these classes)

Comment: Are you aware that half of those classes are third party material and might not be allowed?

Answer (score -1):

not quite a pre-requisite fulfilling ability, but at Mythic Tier 5, you get "Mythic saves"

> Mythic Saving Throws (Ex)
>
> At 5th tier, whenever you succeed at a saving throw against a spell or special ability, you suffer no effects as long as that ability didn’t come from a mythic source (such as a creature with a mythic tier or mythic ranks). If you fail a saving throw that results from a mythic source, you take the full effects as normal.

(src https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alternative-rule-systems/mythic/mythic-heroes/ )